# Me sale error no match for 'operator-'

Tags: c++

En la clase Punt hay un método:

```
double Punt::operator-(const Punt &r){
    return sqrt(pow(a_lat-r.a_lat,2.0)+ pow(a_lon*cos(a_lat/180*M_PI) - r.a_lon*cos(r.a_lat/180*M_PI),2.0))*111319.9;
}
```

Y desde otra clase (Segment) hago esta operación:

Antes de todo, Segment tiene estos atributos:
`list<Punt>s; string nom_segment;`

```
double Segment::longitud() const{
    list<Punt>::const_iterator act=s.begin();
    act++;
    list<Punt>::const_iterator ant=s.begin();
    double longitud=0;
    while(act!=s.end()){
        longitud+=abs((*act)-(*ant));
        ant++;
        act++;
    }
    return longitud;
}
```

Sale error en la línea `longitud+=abs((*act)-(*ant))`, y no entiendo el porqué, si `act` apunta a un Punt i ant también.
Gracias.

Comment: Hola, puedes poner la línea del error completa?

Answer (score 0):

El problema puede parecer mas complicado de lo que es:

Tu función-miembro `longitud()` **está declarada `const`**. Para poder acceder a iteradores de tu variable-miembro de clase `s`, tu variable `act` es del tipo `const iterator`.

El resultado de llamar a un `const_iterator::operator*( )` es una `const &`, es decir, una referencia constante.

Luego haces

```
longitud+=abs((*act)-(*ant))
```

Y el compilador se queja, con toda la razón del mundo, de que `Punt::operator-( const Punt &r )` **no está declarado `const`.**

Puesto que dicho operador no modifica ninguna variable-miembro, no hay ningún motivo para no declararlo así, y el problema desaparece:

```
double Punt::operator-( const Punt &r ) const {
    return sqrt(pow(a_lat-r.a_lat,2.0)+ pow(a_lon*cos(a_lat/180*M_PI) - r.a_lon*cos(r.a_lat/180*M_PI),2.0))*111319.9;
}
```